# How did firefox know to send TCP SYN to port 443?

Tags: tcp

Baby network person just playing around with wireshark to see real life traffic here.

I went to a website on a web browser and saw DNS query/answers and then TCP handshake but SYN being sent to port 443 instead of 80. Is this normal behaviour?
I cant think of a reason how firefox just knew to send directly to 443 instead of 80 on a website it's going for the first time.

As far as I know DNS had nothing to do with HTTPS since it only deals with domain names. And I dont see any other packets before this handshake to explain this. 80 first and redirection to 443 would make more sense.

Help :0

Comment: If either answer helped you, you should accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contary to what ron says I have not heard of any browsers changing the default to https per-se and a google search didn't turn anything up either.

It's difficult to be sure without knowing the site in question but I expect you are seeing one of two things.

The first is HSTS, if a website is in a browsers HSTS list then the browser will never make plain http requests to that site. This is intended to mitigate sslstrip type attacks.

There are two ways a site can get into a browsers HSTS list. Firstly when a https connection is made to the site the site can send a HSTS header adding itself to the list. Secondly HSTS entries can be "preloaded" by the browser vendor, modern browser

A second potential cause is address bar autocomplete. Firefox apparently now preffers https urls over http ones when autocompleting.

A third potential cause is extensions. There are extensions like "https everywhere" that try and push as many requests as possible to https.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent versions of browsers now default to trying HTTPS, first.  There is a big push on to make sure everything is encrypted; it was all over the news a while back.  If HTTPS fails, it will fall back to HTTP.

Comment: I guess that was the only logical explanation (and simplest). Thanks!